# Convert Text to Time with milliseconds

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I paste a time with milliseconds like this `21:34:58.342` into excel, it does not get converted into time format and is stored as text instead. I've tried converting it manually by means of `=--TEXT(A1;"hh:mm:ss.000")` but it produces `#VALUE!` error.

How do I convert time with milliseconds text to time format?

**Update**

If I paste `21:34:58` the value is converted into Time correctly. If I apply `h:mm:ss.000` format to the resulting cell the value is displayed as `21:34:58.000`. But if I edit the cell and add a millisecond to the value `21:34:58.001` it becomes Text.

Comment: Is the cell that you are pasting into formatted as time? Are the quote marks part of what you are pasting? Without using quote marks, I can't replicate what you are describing.

Comment: I've just tried pasting into a cell which format is Time but the result is the same. I'm pasting without the quotes definitely. If I remove the milliseconds component the value is converted to time correclty. If I add milliseconds to a value which is already in Time format it becomes Text. I mean excel shows that the format is still Time but the underlying value is Text.

Comment: Most likely, your system (see *Windows Regional Settings*) decimal separator is **not** a **dot**.  You need to use your system decimal separator when you enter the millisecond value.  Most likely, that is a comma.  You may need to use your system decimal separator in your format string also.

Comment: You are right, Ron. My system's decimal separator is `comma`, but in excel settings I had `dot` defined and hence was expecting excel to recoginize the dot for the milliseconds but it won't recognize either dot or comma in this case. I have just change the setting back to use the system separator and it works correctly with the comma. Thank you!

Comment: I will post my comment as an answer so others might benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, your system (see Windows Regional Settings) decimal separator is **not** a **dot**. You need to use your system decimal separator when you enter the millisecond value. Most likely, that is a `comma`. You may need to use your system decimal separator in your format string also.